# How does image downscaling works with Nearest Neighbour Interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, nearest-neighbor

I have been looking for days how to reduce images with the nearest neighbour interpolation. I find various sources for the enlargement, but not for the reduction. How does this work for following example?
4x4 to 2x2

1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Nearest Neigbor Interpolation, the pixels used are chosen by the reciprocal of the scaling factor. In the example, the scaling factor is 1/2, so the matrix is reduced by a factor of 2. To achieve this, every second (1/scaling_factor) pixel in x and y direction is used. This results in the new matrix:

1 3
3 5